# Search for files in a git repository by extensions

Tags: regex, git, bash, shell

I have a string like this `*.{jpg,png}` for example, but the string could also be just `*.scss` - in fact it is an [editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/).

Then I want to search for every file of this extension which is tracked by my git repository.

I've tried several methods but didn't find any sufficient solution.

The closest one I've got is:
`git ls-tree -r master --name-only | grep -E ".*\.jpg"`

But this is only working for single file extensions not for something like this `git ls-tree -r master --name-only | grep -E ".*\.{jpg,png}"`.

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
git ls-tree -r master --name-only | grep -E '.*\.(jpg|png)'
```

The expression you tried to pass via `-E` option is interpreted as any characters (`.*`), the dot (`\.`), and the string `{jpg,png}`. I guess you are confusing the [Bash brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) with the [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (`|`) in a regular expression [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (the parenthesis).

Consider using the end-of-line anchor: `'.*\.(jpg|png)$'`.

## Without grep

As *@0andriy* pointed out you can pass patterns to `git ls-files` as follows:

```
git ls-files '*.jpg' '*.png'
```

Note, you should escape the arguments in order to prevent the [filename expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) (globbing). In particular, the [asterisk (`*`) character](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html#ASTERISKREG)

> matches any number of repeats of the character string or RE preceding it, including zero instances.

But this obviously will work only for the simple [git patterns](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format). For a slightly more complicated case such as "extension matching *N* characters from a given set" you will need a regular expression (and *grep*, for example).

Comment: Thanks, this is working! So I only need to replace the curly braces with parenthesis and the commas with pipes but that is no problem.
Indeed that is what I did(the confusing stuff).
In my function which is calling the stuff the end of line anchor is already implemented. But for simplicity of this question I just removed all stuff which isn't directly related to my problem.

Comment: @mstruebing, it is better to use the anchor anyways, because `file.jpg.tiff` will match `'.*\.(jpg|png)'`, while  `'.*\.(jpg|png)$'` won't

Comment: *Useless use of grep* as usual. `git ls-files *.jpg *.png` The common rule in *nix is to think twice before using `grep` or `cat` or alike.

Comment: @0andriy, indeed. Only the stars should be escaped in order to prevent the shell expansion (globbing): `git ls-files '*.jpg' '*.png'`. So your command `git ls-files *.jpg *.png` is expanded to `git ls-files a.jpg b.jpg c.jpg d.png e.png ...` where the files are generated from the list of files in the current directory. Besides, the simple git patterns are suitable only in simple cases such as matching only by extension. A slightly more complicated condition such as "extension consisting of N characters from a given set" requires a regular expression.

Comment: `git ls-files *composer.json` is unable to find more than one composer.json besides the one where I called the command from.

Comment: @mstruebing, it is because `composer.json` is in the root. You will not find `some-directory/composer.json` with `git ls-files *composer.json`. Bash applies all kinds of expansions (including globbing), and only then calls the command. `*composer.json` actually builds a list of arguments for the command.

Comment: So I can't use the `git-ls` stuff ==> the grep call is needed

Comment: @mstruebing, you just didn't get.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov, perhaps you update the post to show this option as well?

Comment: @0andriy, updated. @mstruebing, you _can_ use `git ls-files`. Only make sure that the arguments are escaped, and that you are passing the _git patterns_, not regular expressions.